# I have five variables that will have different values based on whether they are in Alaska/US and at half/full resolution

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Question about appropriate data structure:

I have five variables that will have different values 
`string` based on whether they are in US/Alaska and 
at half/full resolution.

So I'm building a 5/2/2 (array or list or dict).

I want to access it with  `x = DStr(var,'AK','H')` ,  e.g..
For Alaska/half-res, what values for OSP/UL/LR/etc, the variables?

This is a static table, values won't change.
There is no obvious ordering to demand 0,1,2 for indices

Problem is, array doesn't like the string indices and
dict wants one key only, not three.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Will all the AK entries be a subset of the U.S. entries, because AK is part of the U.S.? 2. You can use a tuple as a dictionary key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuples to index a dict:

```
>>> values = {
...     ("AK", "H"): ("some", "sample", "data", "to", "return"),
...     ("AK", "F"): ("more", "sample", "data", "for", "you"),
...     # More data here
... }
>>> a, b, c, d, e = values[("AK", "H")]
>>> a
"some"
```

Or you can use a nest of dicts:

```
>>> values = {
...     "AK": {
...         "H": ("some", "sample", "data", "to", "return"),
...         "F": ("more", "sample", "data", "for", "you")
...     },
...     # Other nested dicts here
... }
>>> a, b, c, d, e = values["AK"]["H"]
>>> a
"some"
```

If you have a class structure for defining the 5 data points as a part of a single object (which would be a good idea to keep the data grouped together if it is related), you can store instances of the class instead of the tuples:

```
>>> values = {
...     ("AK", "H"): MyClass("some", "sample", "data", "to", "return"),
...     ("AK", "F"): MyClass("more", "sample", "data", "for", "you"),
...     # More data here
... }
>>> obj = values[("AK", "H")]
>>> obj.osp
"some"
```

or

```
>>> values = {
...     "AK": {
...         "H": MyClass("some", "sample", "data", "to", "return"),
...         "F": MyClass("more", "sample", "data", "for", "you")
...     },
...     # Other nested dicts here
... }
>>> obj = values["AK"]["H"]
>>> obj.osp
"some"
```

Comment: Thanks. I used
 values = {
        ("AK","H"): (OSZ,UL,LR,PROJ,inSDS),
        ("AK","K"): (),
        ("US","H"): (".0046666","-128 52","-52 25","GEO","EV_500),
        ("US","K"): (".0083333","-128 52","-52 25","GEO",EV_250")}

    return values[(region,HQ1)]
###########################################

Comment: Thanks. I used 
values = { 
("AK","H"): (OSZ,UL,LR,PROJ,inSDS),
("AK","K"): (etc),
("US","H"): (etc),
("US","K"): (".0083333","-128 52","-52 25","GEO",EV_250")}
return values[(region,HQ1)] 
& access with PRM(region,HQ1)[2].
This builds a param file to reproject MODIS satellite data to Lat/Lon.
Alaska gets tricky when a swath crosses -180; the program tries to wrap the scene the wrong way around the pole.  So AK -> Polar Stereographic, then later to Lat/Lon.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that your question is rather unclear.  I really don't understand the meaning of the data you want to model, and I don't know how it will be used.

That being said, a class is a good way to define your own data structures.  In this case I guess you have OSP, UL, LR, and "etc".  So I would define a class for that:

```
class MyData:
    def __init__(self, osp, ul, lr, etc):
        self.osp = osp
        self.ul = ul
        self.lr = lr
        self.etc = etc
```

Then make your lookup table containing instances of the class:

```
table = {
    'AK': {'H': MyData(1,5,20,'something'),
           'F': MyData(3,2,28,'spam') },
    'FL': {'H': MyData(42,5,20,'eggs'),
           'F': MyData(2,13,7,'ham') },
    }
```

Then I can define a function matching the signature you showed in your question.  I ignore the argument `var` because your question doesn't tell me anything about it.

```
def DStr(var, state, resolution):
    return table[state][resolution]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed length two strings that will make up a lookup, you can concatenate them together. Might be simpler than having a dict of dict of values. Values can be in a list.

```
table = {'AKH': [1,"two",3.14],
        'AKF': [2,"four", 6.28]
        }
state = 'AK'
res   = 'F'
table[state+res]
```

output

```
[2, 'four', 6.28]
```